# Return latitude and longitude from geometry point type

Tags: postgis

For storing latitude and longitude in the database, I use the following query:

```
WITH cte_posttype AS (
 SELECT posttype_id, code AS posttypeCode FROM "post"."posttype" WHERE code = $6;
)
INSERT INTO "post"."post"(post_id, user_id, fb_username, place_name, geom, posttype_id, status_text, status_img) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3,
   ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($5, $4), 4326),
   SELECT posttype_id FROM cte_posttype,
   $7, $8)
RETURNING post_id, user_id, fb_name, place_name, geom, cte_posttype.posttypeCode, status_text, status_img, updated_at, created_at;
```

The relevant part is:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($5, $4), 4326)
```

Now how do I revert the geometry type back to get the original lat and lng to return it?
The same question applies on making a SELECT: I want to retrieve the lat and lng value to return it to the client as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact provided you always store your points as lon/lat (4326) then just

```
st_x(geom) as lng, st_y(geom) as lat
```

should work.

Comment: Can you answer [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356471/convert-geometry-point-to-coordiantes-in-postgresql) question? Its about converting raw geometry hex values to coordinates

Comment: this answer will work with any geometry